Series in a metric space
I'm studying elementary analysis using Jerrold Marsden's Elementary Classical Analysis textbook. I wondered why series and its convergence is not considered in general metric space, but only in normed vector space.
Is it because addition of multiple points cannot be defined in general metric space? Hence, normed vector space and its concept of vector addition is what makes creating series possible?
I'd be very happy to hear all sorts of information: whether it is okay for me to understand in this manner at the elementary level, or am I misled in some part and there are ways to define addition of points in general metric space. THX

General metric spaces don't have addition operation. You can't even sum $2$ elements, leave alone infinitely many.

Aha, thought there'd be an extra way to go for addition in a more advanced course, thanks.
